# Help for a variant of exercises for textbooks with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to use the basic tool for producing exercises with tcolorbox, in a project of textbook, so I transform the option `lowerbox=ignored` in the option `lowerbox=invisible` to obtain the white space for writing solutions with students, and I remove the command `after upper={...Solution on page...`.

More precisely, I add to `\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}` the options

```
skin=bicolor,
lowerbox=invisible,
colbacklower=white,
```

and I remove the option

```
after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
    {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
```

Now I want to have a title for my solution box, so insert a title in the beginning of the box of solution (I want a title beginning the area in white in my example). How can I do this ?

**A subsidiary (and important) question:** I tried to use the option `skin=bicolor,lowerbox=invisible,colbacklower=white,` on "real conditions", i.e. on all the exercises of a Textbook, where I use several packages, and I obtained the error message :

```
`! Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command..
 \pgfutil@packageerror ...ge {Package #1 Error: #2}`
```

What's the problem here and how can I solve it?

Here is my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
%%    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
%%        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    skin=bicolor,
    lowerbox=invisible,
    colbacklower=white,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex}
An exercise.
\tcblower
A solution
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording


\end{document}
```

and its compilation, using xelatex:

[image]

Comment: What are #1 and #2 arguments of?  it might be easier to use macros like \name and \filename and define them outside the tcolorbox.

Comment: #1 is the label of exercise and #2 is its text. I don't know what is the macro \name, but creating an input file with \filename, and insert it in the tcblower, after "titling" it, seems to be a good idea !

Comment: \input reads files, so I assumed #2 was a filename.  In any case, they aren't defined in this context, at least they do not contain what you think they should contain.

Comment: See the command `label={exercise:#1}` for the use of #1

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: I don't understand your question. I see the title `Solution of....` after using `\tcbinputrecords`. Also the 'subsidiary' question is not useful here -- after adding which packages you get the error?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just want a title for the tcblower... Forget `solution of...`... I've edited my question, you can see it.

Comment: For the 'subsidiary' question, I must debug my file first, to answer your question, in some time perhaps. I wanted to know if it is a known issue between tcolorbox and pgf, so if not, I'll see it deeply later. Thanks

Comment: I still don't get what you are after here -- is it that difficult to post a clear question. `(I want a title beginning the area in white in my example)` -- well, this is no the solution box you are displaying later on with `\tcbinputrecords`. It is the white space where students can fill in their answers.

Comment: Yes. It is the white space where students can fill in their answers. But I want a title for theses answers... something like.. **Answer** in the beginning of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds a node below the `segmentation` line and shifts it inside to be aligned with the left title skip.

The `\kvtcb@X` macros contain the relevant lengths of separation between left upper (X=leftupper) and general box separation (X=boxsep)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\makeatletter
\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper={\quad},
    %after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
    %    {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    skin=bicolor,
    lowerbox=invisible,
    colbacklower=white,
    overlay={\node[right,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (A) at ($(segmentation.south west)+(\kvtcb@leftupper+\kvtcb@boxsep,0)$) {Answer:};}
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}
\makeatother

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex}
An exercise.
\tcblower
A solution
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly my purpose. I don't understand what does the command `\kvtcb`. Can you explain it a little ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: `\kvtcb ...` = key value of tcolorbox `tcb` macros, see the short explanations in the post, however, there is no explanation in the `tcolorbox` manual -- you will only see them if you look into `tcolorbox.sty` -- sometimes, this is necessary

Comment: Good morning. I am trying to re-understand your macro.. so late because I was busy on other things ! So I have an interrogation: why the definition of the exrecise si between  `\makeatletter`and `\makeatother`? Thank you

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Because `\kvtcb@....` are @ - macros, i.e. `at` - letter and as such must be used inside `\makeatletter...\makeatother` to allow `@` to be an ordinary character. We have 'thousands' of questions concerning this ;-)

Comment: Excuse me but I have a serious problem here: with the option `breakable` and if the box exceed one page (I tried with `\lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[3]\lipsum[4]\lipsum[5]`) I have the error message: `! Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command..`. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Try `underlay last` instead of `underlay` -- and there's is a manual for `tcolorbox`!

Comment: I have tried `underlay last` and I have the same message of error. I can't find all this in the manual or/and I can't find the good informationin it ! Many thanks for your disponibility

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: As far as I can see the error message occurs also without using my solution -- it does not seem to related to it

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: None of the examples in the `tcolorbox` manual related to `tcbclipinterior` uses `breakable` -- most likely for good reasons. I doubt that it is possible to combine this

Comment: I think that the problem is in the command `skin=bicolor,`. I tried to comment it and all is good without it.